# How to create resources in azure data lake gen1 with java sdk?

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-sdk

I am new to azure data lake gen1. I am trying to create files and directories with the java sdk.
SO far, I have written this piece of code to perform the creation operation.

```
   final static String clientId =    "b";
   final static String tenantId = "";
   final static String clientSecret = "";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

       String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/b94/oauth2/v2.0/token";
       AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true,    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));
       Future<AuthenticationResult> result = context.acquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/", new    ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), null);
       ADLStoreClient client = ADLStoreClient.createClient("kaushal.azuredatalakestore.net",    result.get().getAccessToken());
       client.createDirectory("/test");

   }
```

I get following error on execution of above code: ---

Exception in thread "main"

> com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLException: Operation MKDIRS
> failed with HTTP403 : AccessControlException Last encountered
> exception thrown after 1 tries [HTTP403(AccessControlException)]

What surprises me is that, I am successfully able to create resources via console but not with the code, I am not trying to find the actual root cause of this error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, although check out a working example as below.

From the portal, you need to add the **execute permission** to the **root** node, if not done already. And don't forget to grant access ADL permissions to your client.

Navigate to your ADL account and then select Access Control (IAM):

1. Register your application (hope thats done already)
2. Navigate to your ADL account and then select Access Control (IAM):
3. Click on +Add to add to add role-based permissions.
4. Under Role select the "Owner". Under Select, select your application. This will grant the "Owner" role for this ADL account to your application.

**Note:** If you are not able to assign the "Owner" role, you can set fine-grained RWX ACL permissions for your application, allowing it access to the files and folders of your ADLS account.

Refer: [Access control in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control)

**Example:** to create a directory named "**kar**" in `ktestadls.azuredatalakestore.net`

```
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CreateDirectory {

    static ADLStoreClient client;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
        setup();
    }

    public static void setup() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        String APP_ID = "<your app id>";
        String APP_SECRET = "<your app secret>";
        String dirName = "/kar";
        String StoreAcct = "ktestadls";

        String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>";
        String resourcUrl = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);

        // Acquire Token
        Future<AuthenticationResult> result = context.acquireToken(
                resourcUrl,
                new ClientCredential(APP_ID, APP_SECRET),
                null
        );
        String token = result.get().getAccessToken();
        System.out.println(token);

        String account = StoreAcct + ".azuredatalakestore.net";
        client = ADLStoreClient.createClient(account, token);

        client.createDirectory(dirName);
        System.out.println("finish.....");

    }
}
```